# \n means 'next line', but what should I do to make a blank tab sapce in same line?

Tags: html, xml

ok... basically, what i want is this..

abcd12345 to

(blank)abcd12345

I know \n does make a new line but what should make a blank tab space in same line?

thanks in advance.

Comment: `\n` does not make a new line in HTML. The Enter/Return key does.

Comment: in html you could use &nbsp;

Comment: string i = "12345 \n 1234"; I should post question like this.. yes.. I admit this question is kinda vague

Comment: is &nbsp also works in xml??

Comment: ah..... nooo.. using &nbsp throws not wellformed xml exception...let me re write my qeustion... yeah.. question seems very vague

Comment: you can use `padding-left` property of css to set your space considerably . ex: `padding-left:10px;` [link](http://jsfiddle.net/VCdvA/351/)

Comment: thanks...  Jonathan \t was what i wanted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "tab space" as in pressing the **Tab** key on your keyboard, you can use `\t`